# Saving a continuous stream of images from ffmpeg image2pipe

Tags: go, ffmpeg

I am trying to save a sequence/continuous images from ffmpeg image2pipe in go. The problem with the code below that it does only save the first image in the stream due to the blocking nature of io.Copy since it waits for the reader or the writer to close.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

//Trying to get png from stdout pipe

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Running the camera stream")
    ffmpegCmd := exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-loglevel", "quiet", "-y", "-rtsp_transport", "tcp", "-i", "rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.1.41:554/h264Preview_01_main", "-r", "1", "-f", "image2pipe", "pipe:1")

    ffmpegOut, err := ffmpegCmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    err = ffmpegCmd.Start()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    count := 0
    for {
        count++
        t := time.Now()
        fmt.Println("writing image" + strconv.Itoa(count))
        filepath := "image-" + strconv.Itoa(count) + "-" + t.Format("20060102150405.png")

        out, err := os.Create(filepath)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer out.Close()

        _, err = io.Copy(out, ffmpegOut)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("unable to copy to file: %s", err.Error())
        }
    }
    if err := ffmpegCmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error while waiting:", err)
    }
}
```

I implemented my own save and copy function based on the io.Copy code https://golang.org/src/io/io.go

```
func copyAndSave(w io.Writer, r io.Reader) error {
    buf := make([]byte, 1024, 1024)
    for {
        n, err := r.Read(buf[:])
        if n == 0 {

        }
        if n > 0 {
            d := buf[:n]
            _, err := w.Write(d)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

    }
    return nil
}
```

then I updated the for loop in my main function to the below block but still I am only getting the first image in the sequence. due to  `r.Read(buf[:])` is being a blocking call.

```
for {
        count++
        t := time.Now()
        fmt.Println("writing image" + strconv.Itoa(count))
        filepath := "image-" + strconv.Itoa(count) + "-" + t.Format("20060102150405.png")

        out, err := os.Create(filepath)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer out.Close()

        err = copyAndSave(out, ffmpegOut)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            log.Fatalf("unable to copy to file: %s", err.Error())
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: I doubt your problem is related to blocking copy. If ffmepg is to output multiple files how do you know when one stops and another one starts? copy is simply copying everything it reads until the pipe closes, so I suspect you have one file with many images concatenated.

Comment: I see, thinking about it now I suspect that ffmpeg is piping the images data to stdout with lines break in between.

Comment: Unlikely. An image is binary data and will contain multiple line breaks. I suggest you discover how ffmpeg writes its output without a pipe. My guess is it'll write it into multiple files, and trying to process such output from a pipe might be futile.